# Magento 1: what does SUPEE stand for?

Tags: magento-1, patches

As you guys may know, the Magento 1 patch names all start with SUPEE and I was wondering if any of you know **what does "SUPEE" stand for** ?

Is that an acronym or a real word ? I have to specify I'm not a native english speaker so I may miss something obvious here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is to do with the JIRA system used for Magento internally. It stands for EE Support so in JIRA I assume you will see SUPEE-404 etc.

See https://twitter.com/piotrekkaminski/status/414091975034277888

Comment: Interesting. When you say EE you mean Enterprise Edition ? Does that means there's some SUPCE as well ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism yeah EE would be Enterprise, I would assume there would be a CE but then again if it is in CE it is also in EE...kind of.

Comment: CE users do not get support by Magento