# What is the idea behind the patch naming for Magento?

Tags: magento-1, patches

**Is there any idea behind the naming of the patches? If yes, what is it?** For those who never saw them (shame on you), some examples below.

- Patch-7405
- Patch-8788
- Patch-1533

Full list in second tab "Release archive" here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

**EDIT**: this question explains the "SUPEE" part as commented below: [What is the idea behind the patch naming for Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142054/what-is-the-idea-behind-the-patch-naming-for-magento)
I am wondering if ***the numbers*** have any meaning and what they stand for.

Comment: could be the number of the issue in their bug tracker...but not sure.

Comment: Probably @SherrieRohde could answer that, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an additional explanation to this: [Magento 1: what does SUPEE stand for?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138304/magento-1-what-does-supee-stand-for)

The number after the patch is the JIRA ticket number related to the patch (used by Magento internally).